# Newbie with python requests

Tags: python, httprequest

I am just starting out with Python and Requests and was having a go at trying to get some exchange rates.

I tried this:

```
import requests

params={'base_currency_0':'EUR','quote_currency':'GBP','end_date':'2019-09-21','view':'details','id':'1','action':'C'}

res=requests.get('https://www1.oanda.com/currency/converter/update?',params=params)
```

but keep getting an error.

I would love for someone to be able to point me in the right direction and help this newbie out.

Comment: "but keep getting an error"—what does it say? Error messages usually contain useful information. Please read [ask].

Comment: `https://www1.oanda.com/currency/converter/update?` returns error from the browser, are you sure that this site supports what you are trying to do?

Comment: The get request returns an error even when executed from a browser and responds with status code 500, probably because the site uses cloudflare bot management.

Comment: Hello,  the error is indeed 500 and that's all I get back in python.  the site definitely supports what I want to do because I can do the same thing as an XMLHTTP request in Excel VBA so I know it works and can be done...….I just don't know how to do it in Python as Im so new!!!

Answer (score 0):

the error is indeed 500 and that's all I get back in python. the site definitely supports what I want to do because I can do the same thing as an XMLHTTP request in Excel VBA so I know it works and can be done...….I just don't know how to do it in Python as Im so new!!!